# Assembly.LoadFile works but AppDomain.Load fails

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-assembly

I want to do a simple Extension application that loads extensions at runtime, then chooses one and executes a method in the selected extension based on an interface (not using MAF or MEF etc) but I'm getting weird errors loading the AppDomain. The extension dll and all the dlls next to it in the bin/Debug folder are in a specified folder and I can load the extension dll using `Assembly.LoadFile` how ever when I try `AppDomain.Load` I get a `FileNotFoundException`, can anyone suggest why this would happen? My code is below

```
var extensionName = loadedExtension.Name;
var extensionFolder = Path.Combine(extensionsRootDirectory, extensionName);
if (!Directory.Exists(extensionFolder)) continue;

Assembly assmbl = null;
IProvider provider = null;
string assemblyName = null;
//Find entry point Assembly
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(extensionFolder, "*.dll"))
{
    try
    {
        assmbl = Assembly.LoadFile(filePath); //This loads the assembly without problems
        var types = assmbl.GetTypes();
        var providerType = (from t in assmbl.GetTypes()
            where t.GetInterface(typeof(IInfonProvider).Name) != null
            select t).FirstOrDefault();
        if (providerType != null)
        {
            assemblyName = assmbl.FullName;
            provider = assmbl.CreateInstance(providerType.FullName) as IInfonProvider;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { /*Continue, will handle problem if no file was loaded from folder*/ }
}

if (assemblyName != null)
{
    try
    {                       
        var appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
            {
                //ApplicationName = extensionName,
                //DynamicBase = extensionFolder,
                ApplicationBase = extensionFolder,
                PrivateBinPath = extensionFolder
            };

        var extensionDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(extensionName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, appDomainSetup);
        extensionDomain.Load(assemblyName); //This gives FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'CNSProvider,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Comment: I've just seen that Assembly.LoadFile gives me the same error as AppDomain.Load when I attempt to instantiate my type from the assembly. SO the question is actually: How do I determine which file is actually missing as? The file in the error message is there, it must be one of the 'or its dependencies'. How would I go about finding out which file it is looking for? To my knowledge all dependencies is in the same folder as my main dll

Comment: Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  *Never* use LoadFile() it doesn't provide a loading context.  Consider LoadFrom() if the file isn't in the probing path.

Answer (score 2):

try using CurrentDomain

```
string fileToLoad = @"C:\myApp.dll";

AssemblyName assamblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileToLoad);
AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;                     
Assembly myAssambly = myDomain.Load(assamblyName);
```